# Como criar um modulo para uma pasta específica?

Tags: golang

opa, tudo beleza? Tentei criar um módulo em linguagem Go no visual studio. O módulo é referente à uma pasta chamada "1 - Pacotes". mas quando escrevo o código só aparece isso. Tô começando em programação e não entendo muito.

```
PS C:\Users\arthu\OneDrive\Documentos\5. Programação\Visual Studio\Golang> cd 1\ -\ Pacotes/
Set-Location : Não é possível localizar um parâmetro posicional que aceite o argumento '-\'.
No linha:1 caractere:1
+ cd 1\ -\ Pacotes/   
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Location], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
 
PS C:\Users\arthu\OneDrive\Documentos\5. Programação\Visual Studio\Golang>
```

Comment: Ajudaria se você colocasse o seu código e a estrutura do seu projeto na pergunta. Outra informação que é bom você esclarecer é se o seu projeto foi inicializado como `Go Module` ou não, pois se não foi o Go só irá conseguir importar as dependências se o seu projeto estiver dentro do `Go Path`

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, o erro que deu para você é referente ao powershell ou cmd e não a linguagem GO.

O problema se refere a tentar usar o comando cd.

Ele está interpretando o -\ em "cd 1\ -\ Pacotes/" como um parametro para o comando cd.

Se você tentar entrar na pasta usando:

```
cd '.\1 - Pacotes\'
```

Irá funcionar, abraços.